# What is the namespace and app name for django auth urls?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using the Django built-in auth function.

```
path('account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

When I try to reference it using `{% url 'password_reset' %}` as seen in the Django code. I get an error. How do I reference it? There doesn't seem to be any namespace or app_name in the Django source. The answers on Stack Overflow are either outdated or require one to manually rebuild the URL one by one and reference it.

Comment: This will help you. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Comment: Thanks, I found out that after I moved the auth url out of my app, a single ```password_reset``` works. Which means that if I had do ```app_name:password_reset``` it would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

I found that after moving the authentication URL out of my app's `urls.py`, `{% url 'password_reset' %}` works, which means that the `app_name` inherits that of my app.

`{% url 'app_name:password_reset' %}` would have worked before I moved the authentication URL.